# Error: ('IM005', "[IM005] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_DBC failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cursor, pyodbc

I am running this code in my pyodbc script where I am trying to do parallelism

```
templst = [lineitem, orders, partsupp, region, cur_cur, T1, T2]
connstr = [DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=lint16muthab.phl.sap.corp:8766;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8, DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8767;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8,
           DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8768;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8,
           DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8769;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8, DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8770;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8]

def extract_single(q, cursorconn):
    while True:
        try:
            tableName = q.get_nowait()
            time.sleep(3)
            qry2 = "Select * FROM %s"% (tableName)
            print " extraction done of table:%s done by cursor:%s"%(tableName,cursorconn)
        except Queue.Empty:
            return

def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for item in templst:
        q.put(item) # add items to queue
    process = []
    for i in xrange(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=extract_single, args=(q, connstr[i]))
        process.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in process:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output is like :

```
  extraction done of table:lineitem done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=lint16muthab.phl.sap.corp:8766;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8
```

extraction done of table:orders done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8767;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8

```
      extraction done of table:partsupp done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8768;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8

      extraction done of table:region done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8769;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8

      extraction done of table:cur_cur done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8770;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8

     extraction done of table:T2 done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=localhost:8767;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8

     extraction done of table:T1 done by cursor:DRIVER={libdbodbc17.so};host=lint16muthab.phl.sap.corp:8766;UID=dba;PWD=sql;CharSet=utf8
```

But when I modify my extract function into

```
def extract_single(q, cursorconn):
    while True:
        try:
            tableName = q.get_nowait()
            time.sleep(3)
            conn = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)
            cursor = connvar.cursor()
            qry2 = "Select * FROM %s"% (tableName)
            cursor.execute(qry2).fetchall()
            print " extraction done of table:%s done by cursor:%s"%(tableName,cursorconn)
        except Queue.Empty:
            return
```

I am getting error and not able to open a connection and cursor on that so that I can execute this query and dump data into files.

```
2Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn3.py", line 86, in extract_single
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    connvar = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Error: ('IM005', "[IM005] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_DBC failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn3.py", line 86, in extract_single
    connvar = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)
Error: ('IM005', "[IM005] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_DBC failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn3.py", line 86, in extract_single
    connvar = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)
```

for all connections. Please let me know how to resolve this error.
  **Error getting while using cursor object**

I want to use cursor object which I have stored in a form of list instead of opening a new connection again and everytime open a cursor.
cursorlist will look like

```
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7fcd9b47f270> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7fcd9b47f330> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7fcd9b47f390> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7fcd9b47f3f0> <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7fcd9b47f450>
```

So I have 5 cursor objects 
and table list same as above

```
def extract_single(q, cursorconn):
    while True:
        try:
            tableName = q.get_nowait()

            qry2 = "Select count(*) FROM %s"%(tableName)
            cursorconn.execute(qry2)
            rowcnt = cursorconn.fetchone()[0]
            print " rows in tempdsc=",rowcnt
            print " extraction done of table:%s done by cursor:%s"%(tableName,cursorconn)

        except Queue.Empty:
            return



def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for item in tempdsclst:
        q.put(item) # add items to queue
    process = []
    for i in xrange(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=extract_single, args=(q, curlst[i]))
        process.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in process:
        p.join()
```

it gives error like

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn4.py", line 87, in extract_single
    cursorconn.execute(qry2)
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn4.py", line 87, in extract_single
    cursorconn.execute(qry2)
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn4.py", line 87, in extract_single
    cursorconn.execute(qry2)
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn4.py", line 87, in extract_single
    cursorconn.execute(qry2)
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
Process Process-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/sybopt/software/python/python/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "conn4.py", line 87, in extract_single
    cursorconn.execute(qry2)
Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

Comment: I see in the stacktrace `connvar = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)`  but you show the source to be `conn = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0`. So if you want help with this, you will need to edit your question and post your *actual* source. And is your `connstr` variable really what you show it to be?

Comment: @Booboo  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62244653/13193575 . Please check this link where I am passing cursor object but getting error. Yes connect string is correct because I am able to do connect it manually but not with process code

Comment: How many times are you going to post the same error as separate questions?

Comment: Thats a different error which I am getting while using cursor object. Its not same error as this

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the problem you are having, based on your earlier question I had assumed that `cursorconn` was an already opened connection that would be reused for each query. Since it now appears to be just a connection string (although in your code it doesn't seem to be an actual string, which is the same situation for the items in list `templst` ???), then you should be making the call `conn = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)` *before* the `while True:` statement so that the same connection can be reused for multiple queries and you should then close the connection before you return from the function.

I think the problem is the statement `cursor = connvar.cursor()`, which should be: `cursor = conn.cursor()`. So, try the following:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(cursorconn, timeout=0)
while True:
    try:
        tableName = q.get_nowait()
        time.sleep(3) # why is this here?
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        qry2 = "Select * FROM %s"% (tableName)
        cursor.execute(qry2).fetchall()
        print " extraction done of table:%s done by cursor:%s"%(tableName,cursorconn)
        cursor.close() # should probably add this
    except Queue.Empty:
        return
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: I am still getting that error while passing connection string. Even I want to use cursor object but that also is not working and it is throwing a different as mentioned in  Error getting while using cursor object. Please have a look at error